# Heating vacuum tube filament via capacitor

Tags: capacitor, ac, vacuum-tube, reactance

As I understand vacuum tubes (like triode / pentode) usually are designed to be heated with certain current through the filament.

And usually it is about low-voltage and comparatively high-current. E.g. 6.3 V at 300mA.

Schematics I usually find around use transformer to get this heating voltage. I wonder, whether I can instead connect heater filament directly to 220V AC via suitable capacitor to limit current. E.g. I think 4.7 uF should provide about the said 330mA. And it can feed several lamps in chain.

What could be the drawbacks? I can suppose that temperature will be pulsating slightly (like incandescent bulbs do about 5% light pulsation) and this can affect the anode current... But vacuum tubes have slower temperature time-constant...

UPD: some clarification - this scheme of course should only be considered for isolated filament (how do we call it... indirect cathode heating?).

Also "simplified" calculation `I=Uac*(w*C)` which I mean is correct only while total voltage on filament (or chain of filaments) is small in comparison to full Uac.

Comment: Think about it for a moment.  You are using the capacitor as a voltage divider, with the heater filament as the second part of the divider.  If you add more tubes in series, you change the divider ratio.  Also, heater filaments aren't simple resistors.  Like light bulb filaments, their resistance is low when cold and higher when hot.

Comment: Interesting approach. Be careful with placing un-isolated 220 volts between filament and cathode.

Comment: Any "capacitive dropper" supply has a poor power factor. Probably not a big deal even at this current but certainly not "nice". There might be unexpected behavior if the filament isn't on a voltage close to ground.

Comment: @JRE no, not voltage divider but rather current limiter. Remember they have voltages "orthogonal" and thus while one of the legs (voltage on the filaments) is small compared to hypotenuse, current is almost unchanged. It is correct about filament resistance raising with heat but again it has little-to-no effect on the current (while voltage on the filament is small).

Comment: The RC highpass filter disagrees.

Comment: And, **yes** voltage divider.

Comment: @JRE ok, ok, it is a voltage divider in complex numbers, and if calculated thoroughly, we find again that current changes only few percents for both single 6.3V filament or series of 3 or 4 such filaments. Any voltage divider with one half having much larger resistance than other could be regarded as current limiter, right?

Comment: Long ago, there was a 5-tube radio whose filaments were wired in series, driven by 120V AC: 50V + 35V + 12V + 12V +12V (all indirectly heated cathodes). I recall that one or more flared alarmingly at turn-on until all thermally stabilized. Have also seen a series *resistor* to take up the slack...never a capacitor.

Comment: @glen_geek - yep, I think you mean All-American-5 - I mentioned them in some other comment. Though I'm not old enough to remember them alive - and too far geographically :) Thanks for interesting note about unequal heat-up!

Comment: @glen_geek Indeed - AA5s do have substantial inrush currents as the filament/heater chain comes up to temperature. But, tubes (esp. their filaments) are very forgiving things vis a vis their solid state brothers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AC voltage on the heater will drive the filament to a positive voltage every half cycle. Any voltage difference with respect to the cathode will draw electron current away from the cathode, thus modulating the voltage gain of the tube at AC frequency.  Likely highly undesirable.

Comment: Many tube circuits use AC for the heater filament.  They are designed for that.

Comment: Ah, yes. I clearly missed this. 300V swing to both positive and negative - comparable or more than anode voltage.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JRE they are designed for roughly 6V AC, not 220AC... Interesting to check how AA5 was designed in this respect, I think they have higher-voltage filaments.

Comment: Filaments are usually driven from a separate winding on the transformer so they're isolated from the anode and cathode and won't cause a current to flow.

Comment: simply tie one end of the filament to GND, and other end to the voltage-dropping capacitor. The cap handles most of the 220 volts.

Comment: In early European color TVs, using a lot of tubes, all filaments were connected in series, tube names starting with "P" were designed for that, all made for 300 mA with various voltages. The gap to 220 V was completed with a resistor, sometimes a diode was added to make the gap smaller.  Philips "Goya" even had two strings. I do not remember any case of cathode modulation, even at 220 VAC, and I repaired a lot of them.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder, whether I can instead connect heater filament directly to 220V AC via suitable capacitor to limit current. [...] What could be the drawbacks?

Well, the primary drawback would be the dramatic increase in deadliness of whatever device you're trying to avoid putting a mains transformer in.  As others have mentioned, in the Before Time(tm), companies were somehow allowed to get away with exactly what you're describing (the AA5's, too many guitar amps, etc. etc.).  This is thankfully no longer allowed in general (and certainly nowhere a vacuum tube would be used today, i.e. some type of audio amplifier).

Even if you were to limit the discussion to heaters only, and were otherwise properly using a mains transformer for the HT+, the safety hazard still exists: e.g., heater-to-cathode shorts do happen, and when they do, you would now have your circuit ground and all the exposed metalwork connected to it now shorted to the AC mains through a ~1.5K resistor and a cap (neither rated to handle 220VAC BTW).  So now you have a live chassis.  Not good.

For much more information, dive into the regulatory requirements covering the different electrical safety classes, e.g. Class I and Class II would be the most applicable here.

This truly is one of those "never, ever, consider doing this" sort of things we occasionally run into in our field.  Always put in a proper mains transformer between the mains and any vacuum tube (or other) device you're designing.

Comment: I agree that it’s not the best idea from electrical safety perspective, but a DIN-rail mounted GFCI mounted inside the unit would go a long way towards catching heater-to-cathode shorts. If the unit is a self-contained radio with no external exposed antenna connections, and all the controls are insulated, as well as the case, to provide double insulation - then it should be about as safe as anything else with double insulation. An external antenna connection would need a safety-rated coupling transformer. Two coils on opposite sides of a thin glass sheet would be fancy way to do it.